# Add shortcuts to home button long press menu

Tags: stock-android, launcher, google-now, home-button, xposed-framework

Is there a way to add app launchers to the stock android's home button long press menu? I know you're able to do this in CM, but there must be some Xposed module, right?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gravitybox lets you set navigation ring targets via the Xposed Framework.

---

[image]
[image]